# How can i get the Facebook page like count without login?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like

I need to get the facebook page like count without user login. I want to show the count on my webpage. I don't want an FB Button, need to show the count only. I saw that several people are using graph api, But I think it requires an accesstoken, so it also required to login by the user. I don't want that kind of stuffs. Guys help me with a solution. I will also trying, if I get a solution before, will comment here.

Comment: Theres a reason, why facebook has an api ...

Comment: You want to get the like count from with Javascript?

Comment: @DavidAntoon, Yeah Js is helpful to me,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be the API call:

`https://graph.facebook.com/[page-id]?fields=name,fan_count&access_token=[any-access-token]`

The response (JSON):

```
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "fan_count": 216,
  "id": "xxx"
}
```

About Tokens in general:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Answer (score 5):

## GET Request + Regex

To get pages likes you can perform **GET** request to this Facebook link with your page:

> http://www.facebook.com/plugins/fan.php?connections=100&id={PAGE_ID}

and then find the like count with regex.

Comment: Get and $('._1drq').text();