# Fetch facebook page likes using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

To fetch facebook page's likes, I tried the following code

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/champstest" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-size="small" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>


<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.12&appId=148617302637200&autoLogAppEvents=1';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

And also referred [How can i get the Facebook page like count without login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39085030/how-can-i-get-the-facebook-page-like-count-without-login)

Which returns following error

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#200) Access to this data is temporarily disabled for non-active apps or apps that have not recently accessed this data due to changes we are making to the Facebook Platform. https://developers.facebook.com/status/issues/205942813488872/",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 200,
      "fbtrace_id": "EzzXKz0aYcY"
   }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i get the Facebook page like count without login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39085030/how-can-i-get-the-facebook-page-like-count-without-login)

Comment: no, it isn't @Occam'sRazor

Comment: it is possible with client side js only, but not recommended, as you would need to hardcode an access token. make sure you know about access tokens, you can read about them in my answer in the other thread. tokens need to be kept secret.

Comment: I'm working in HubSpot, So Client side JS is only option i have...  @luschn

Comment: Tough luck, then you simply can not implement this properly in any other way, than making the visitors of this website login to your Facebook app first, so that you can then use their user access token for this.

Comment: @luschn How i can solve this via hardcoded access token.

I have used https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/<page_id>?fields=about,fan_count,website&access_token=<access_token> 

But this returns me error with code 200

Comment: again, you need to keep tokens secret. you can only do what CBroe mentioned. and please, if you get an error, include the error message. no developer will be able to help you if you just comment "there is an error".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook API is currently degraded and there's probably no way to get this to work right now.

> We are pausing all new messaging experiences (including new authentications on approved apps) on the platform while we review our policies and make necessary adjustments.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/status/issues/104197713763517/